# CSS Interactation (Pointer) Media Query at risk?

Tags: css, media-queries

[W3C's Media Query Level 4 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#pointer) (updated May 19, 2017) now states that interactive media queries are "at risk." **What does this mean?**

[According to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction), this feature has already been adopted by most modern browsers and I was strongly considering implementing a strategy for hover effects that relies on this technology, but this "at risk" notice gives me pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document itself explains this tag:

> The following features are at-risk, and may be dropped during the CR period:
>
> - the hover, any-hover, pointer, and any-pointer media features
>
> “At-risk” is a W3C Process term-of-art, and does not necessarily imply that the feature is in danger of being dropped or delayed. It means that the WG believes the feature may have difficulty being interoperably implemented in a timely manner, and marking it as such allows the WG to drop the feature if necessary when transitioning to the Proposed Rec stage, without having to publish a new Candidate Rec without the feature first.
>
> -- https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#status

Comment: That's helpful, but now I wonder what the odds are of it getting dropped during CR.

Comment: @Dresden That I don't know.  It sounds pretty safe to use, however; especially if all you're using it for is unique hover effects for those non-precise platforms.  That should be easy to build with adequate fallbacks in case it is removed.